# difference between cgi and webservice

Tags: web-services, cgi

Can any one tell me the main differences between CGI application and webservice. I have been googling but could not found any better answers.

I just know that CGI was found earlier than webservice.

Answer (score 7):

CGI (Common Gateway Interface) is a way for webservers to start external applications (and pass reuqest information to the application) in order to provide dynamic contents.

A webservice is also some kind of dynamic content and can be implemented using CGI applications (or similar methods). However, for webservices the content is machine readable (XML) and has to follow a strict specification. Thus, webservices aim for being used automatically by other programs.

The general idea of CGI is still used today, however, it has some drawbacks (e.g., for every request a new application has to be started on the server). Nowadays it's more common to have modules/plugins loaded into the webserver which handle the execution of scripts (e.g., mod-php, mod-perl - there the parser is loaded once and just has to execute the requested scripts).

Comment: Thank for the answer. 
so what i understand here is in case of CGI we have some application or lets say API which we are calling or executing from HTTP request via CGI.
But in case of webservice we are publishing the entire API/Application or some part of it to the clients.
So my question is the CGI and Webservices are completely inter changeable.

Comment: No. CGI is an interface which allows the webserver to execute applications (based on an URL) instead of just serving static files. Webservices are dynamic applications (implemented CGI applications - or using a different webserver API nowadays) which, however, do not input/ouput HTML but XML with a specific syntax to provide their own API. It works like this: The client calls the webserver and that might call a CGI application and service it with the request details and returns the output to the client. Webservices lay on top of that (the webservice data is the payload of the CGI application).

Comment: Thank you again sir. Is there any security issues with webservices? I feel that CGI is more secure as we have application separated from front end. but in case of webservice the part of application is exposed to front end.

Comment: Generally speaking there is no difference. The browser (or any web service client) sends its data to the server and that is passed to the CGI application, that performs some calculations and returns the results. Webservices are just better for handling automatically (you use XML instead of HTML which is hard to parse). If you don't protect yourself against common threats (SQL injection, ...) you can shoot yourself in the foot with both technologies.

Answer (score -3):

CGI vs. Web Server APIs
The Common Gateway Interface (CGI) was introduced as a standard protocol for extending the functionality of Web servers with additional applications. Most CGI applications are simple executables that are launched every time they are requested. ColdFusion uses a more robust architecture. The ColdFusion Application Server runs as a multi-threaded system service and handles all of the complicated processing. The Application Server communicates with the Web server either through a very small CGI executable referred to as the stub (cfml.exe) or through a native Web server API.

As Web servers have developed, each vendor has introduced and implemented an application programming interface (API) for their server. The native Web server APIs offer additional features and significantly increased performance. Instead of launching a CGI executable, servers supporting an API communicate directly with the ColdFusion application server through a DLL.

In addition to introducing server APIs, many server vendors have created document type mapping, so that individual document extensions can be associated with a process. This makes it possible to create ColdFusion application pages that are stored directly in the Web server's root directory.

ColdFusion supports the following major native Web server APIs:

- Netscape API (NSAPI)
- Internet Server
- API (ISAPI)
- Website API (WSAPI)
- Apache API

These APIs and document type mapping are supported by these servers:

- Netscape Enterprise and FastTrack Servers
- Microsoft IIS (all versions)
- WebSite (1.1 and Pro)
- Apache
- List item

Comment: Please don't copy paste answers from other websites as it is. Summarize and provide the link to original answer.